# Create an observable list with type Field

Tags: java, arrays, list, javafx

Is there a way to create an observableList that holds Field values?

I tried this:

```
ObservableList<Field> fieldList = FXCollections.observableList(); //tells me 'cannot resolve method observableList()'
```

I am getting the variable names from a Person class like this:

```
Field[] fieldValues = Person.class.getDeclaredFields();
```

I do this to get values for header Values in tablecolumns and want them to be stored in an observableList instead of an array.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FXCollections.observableList` allows you to pass a list that is used to store the info:

```
List<Field> backingList = ... // set some non-observable list here
ObservableList<Field> fieldList = FXCollections.observableList(backingList);
```

In this case I recommend simply using `FXCollections.observableArrayList` tough:

```
ObservableList<Field> fieldList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(Person.class.getDeclaredFields());
```